# Alignment of form fields

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment, margin

I am trying to create a form to create a new user for my website. I would like to have the form fields horizontally aligned, to make it look nicer. I have tried doing this using some simple CSS, but I cannot get it to work*.

```
<html>
    <form name="newUserForm" method="post" action="createUserScript.php">
        <p>Username:           <input name="username" type="text" autofocus class="formField"> </p>  
        <p>E-mail:             <input name="email" type="text" class="formField">              </p>
        <p>Password:           <input name="password" type="text" class="formField">           </p>
        <p>Repeat password:    <input name="passwordRepeat" type="text" class="formField">     </p>
        <p>Administrator:      <input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" class="formField">        </p>
    </form>
</html>
```

And the CSS for the `.formField` class is

```
.formField {
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

The whole thing is located in a `<div>` with the following properties (I dont know if this has anything to say)

```
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

Currently it seems to be making the margin from where the text ends, but I am not sure. What am I missing here?

*I could probably find some crazy workaround to make it work, but I cannot think of anything that seems reasonable.

Comment: You actually need to read on the basics of css and html to geta better understanding of the different values of the display property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'd do (using labels):

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
        label{display:block; float:left; width:130px;}
        .formFeild{width:200px;}
        p{clear:both; margin-bottom:5px;}
    </style>

    <form name="newUserForm" method="post" action="createUserScript.php">
        <p><label>Username:</label><input name="username" type="text" autofocus class="formField"> </p>  
        <p><label>E-mail:</label><input name="email" type="text" class="formField">              </p>
        <p><label>Password:</label><input name="password" type="text" class="formField">           </p>
        <p><label>Repeat password:</label><input name="passwordRepeat" type="text" class="formField">     </p>
        <p><label>Administrator:</label><input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" class="formField">        </p>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: I personnally prefer inline-block display over floating. An ordered list may also be better semantically. But this anyway answers the question so +1 :-)

Comment: That seems to be a quite decent solution. Makes me wonder why I didn't think of that myself...

Comment: A possible problem with this is the fixed width of labels. But this is not a big problem when talking about 1 form with a limited amount of fields

Answer (score 3):

Another thing you can do is use table alignment. That way you don't have to pick a width:

```
<form>
  <p><label>Username:</label><input>
  <p><label>Password:</label><input>
  <p><label>Shoe size:</label><input>
  <p><label>Favorite color:</label><input>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form {
  display: table;
}

form > p {
  display: table-row;
}

form > p > label, form > p > input {
  display: table-cell;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

[Here's a CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/hukds)  You can also do this with a `<ul>` if you've got some name/value pairs outside of a form:

```
<ul class=pairs>
  <li><label>Whatever:</label><p>Some stuff ...
  <li><label>Something Else:</label><p>More stuff ...
</ul>
```

The `<ul>` would be the table, each `<li>` is a row, and the `<label>` and `<p>` elements are the cells.

Comment: In this case, could we consider an html table semantically correct ? Column 1 would be for labels, column 2 for input fields as simulated by your css code, and this could be considered tabular arrangement... As a side note and hoping not to look like a semantic nazi, I consider ordered list a better semantic approach for forms as some random arrangement may look very weird...

Comment: @Bartdude well, that's probably an argument for the hair-splitter crowd. Personally I prefer the simpler (non-table) markup because I think it's cleaner, and it's closer to being semantically appropriate (though I admit that that's not *super* important to me).

Comment: Holy duck,m now it's getting fancy... How is the support for this sort of code in older browsers?

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help. It's always nice to have options :-)

Comment: Semantic is most of the time hair-splitting... Maybe that's why I like it :-)